# What happens if a druid is wild shaped as an Earth elemental and gets turned into stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, conditions, wild-shape

In a D&D 5th edition game I'm running the PCs fought against Gorgons. The druid was wild shaped into an earth elemental (moon druid). The druid got turned to stone by failing two saves in a row to the gorgon's breath. What happens in this situation?

**Is he a statue of a an earth elemental, or a statue of a druid?
If he is an earth elemental, could you break the statue, doing enough damage to kill the earth elemental but not kill the druid, and would that free him, or just turn him into a statue of a druid instead of an earth elemental?**

I can't seem to find rules on this anywhere.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Earth Elementals are immune to petrification.

See the Earth Elemental stat block:

> **Condition Immunities** Exhaustion, Paralyzed, *Petrified*, Poisoned, Unconscious

The Earth Elemental can never be petrified, so we don't have to wonder what happens when they are petrified.

Comment: good call, I didn't even notice this, though would be good to know in the future if he wild shaped into something that is not immune

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco What this doesn't answer is what happens when the chosen wild shape form is not immune to petrify, so it may be worth asking a new question, focusing on what happens when the statue is reduced to 0 hit points while still in wild shape form.

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco To that end, I've reverted your last edit, I recommend making a new question focusing on what happens when the statue is reduced to 0 hit points.

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco Ive changed the title here to more clearly differentiate it from that question as well. I think it's a good question to post.

Comment: I can't remember how to link the questions as related, but might be a good idea if oyu know how

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco adding a link to the other question would make it go in linked questions, which is arguably better. but it's in related questions already anyway